# Saving and converting between timezones in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP/MySQL to for my web application. I am trying to safe users’ timezone (USER A) along with their entries in their respective database table fields and the PHP timezone_identifiers_list() function has been very helpful in providing the different timezones that permits the users do so. User B will need the data converted to his/her own timezone on querying this data. For this conversion I am faced with two choices:

1. Converting on MySQL: I could use CONVERT_TZ(‘2017-02-01 20:00:00’, '+00:00', '+01:00'), but the function does not support say: CONVERT_TZ(‘2017-02-01 20:00:00’, 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Douala'), whereas timezone_identifiers_list() only returns data like ‘Africa/Accra’, making it not a good choice.
2. Conversion by PHP: Given that USER A’s data will be looped for the conversion to be done per data row, I am still hesitant to doing the conversion in PHP.

I will like to know if there is a better way of doing this conversion.

Comment: This is opinion based. So do it in PHP! :-)

Comment: Make sure you save it in universal time and make sure you build it with php datetime object. You can define the local time in the visitors browser by providing the datetime object with the local timezone. See link: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to configure your servers and your PHP application to use UTC timezone, and to never operate any conversion.

Timezone configuration is attached to each users, and even better automatically configured in each users browsers, so you can leverage tools like [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) within your frontend application.

Comment: I am on a shared server and I don't want to set a global timezone. I am not too good at dtabase administartion, but this is what I am aiming at (please pardon me if I express MySQL loopholes in my description). I don't want to depend on the server's session timezone, but get user A's date via HTML5 time inout field and save it along with user A's chosen timezone  and user B's timezone will come to convert user A's timezone to user B's timezone when user B queries the database. Therefore the user A's time is more of a constatnt and the two timezones (that of user A and B) the variables